# R loop, error: "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

I am getting this error and don't know why it comes. can anyone please help ?

> `Error in if (Load_profile$Demand[[i]] > Load_profile$discharge.rate2[[i]]) { : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

This is the loop:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: You didn't share a reproducible example of your data, so hard to say for sure.  But I would guess one side of inequality condition has an NA value for a certain index i.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  There is no way for us to help you without some background on what `Load_profile` is and/or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: And don't post pictures of code. Post the actual code so it can be copy/pasted, examined, etc.